# Warning "Use of GNU statement expression extension"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-4.0

I have this Objective-C istruction:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i, MIN(a, b));
```

where `a` and `b`are `NSUInteger`s.

`MIN()` is the macro defined in the standard `NSObjCRuntime.h`header file as:

```
#if !defined(MIN)
   #define MIN(A,B) ({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __typeof__(B) __b = (B); __a < __b ? __a : __b; })
#endif
```

During the compilation, the LLVM Compiler 4.1 highlights my instruction showing the warning: "Use of GNU statement expression extension".

What does this mean? Is it my fault? If yes, how can I fix it? If not, how can I remove the compiler warning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s a late answer, I know, but you can avoid this message by adding `-Wno-gnu` to your compiler flags.

(In Xcode 5 I believe you can change this by going to your project’s Build Settings and adding `-Wno-gnu` to the “Other C Flags”, which are in the “Apple LLVM 5.0 – Custom Compiler Flags” section.)

Answer (score 12):

"Statement expressions" is an extension of the GNU C compiler and allows you to execute a group of statements, returning the value of the last statement:

```
x = ({
    statement1;
    statement2;
    statement3;
});
```

In the above example, `x` will have the value returned by `statement3`.

It is a convenient feature that enables you to have multi-statement macros that can be nested easily into other expressions. It is not, however, defined by any C standard.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting. Since the `MIN()` macro is defined in the Apple headers (which I can't obviously change), there is a way to suppress this warning in my code?

Comment: @Dev You should just be able to do *`#undef MIN`*. That goes for all *`#define`* s.

Answer (score 10):

Don't use `-Wno-gnu`, that shuts down too many warnings. Instead, use:

```
-Wno-gnu-statement-expression
```

Comment: the pragma statement would be:
 `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu-statement-expression" `

Comment: @Ugo With that, I get `error: unknown option after ‘#pragma GCC diagnostic’ kind [-Werror=pragmas]`. I'm compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Statement expressions have been declared.

You can selectively ignore the warning by using pragma codes without changing project settings.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu"

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i, MIN(a, b));

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```